# AWS EC2 Windows 2008 Server - Where is Daylight Savings Time?

Tags: windows-server-2008, daylight-saving

I have a server running Windows 2008 on Amazon EC2. It's a standard Amazon AMI, without any major tweaks. The default time zone is "UTC".

I'm going to run an application that requires the server to be on the same time zone as Great Britain. At the moment, that is British Summer Time, but I'd like to have the usual automatic switch back to GMT in the winter.

When I look at the "Time Zone Settings" dialogue box there's no option for "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Savings Time".

[image]

Where is this option located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select a time zone that has daylight savings for that checkbox to appear.  Select your timezone first, then check the checkbox.

Comment: Yup, that was it! I needed to change from UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) to UTC (Dublin, London, etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right below timezone... Click "Change time zone.." on the Date and Time dialog, and its there.

In the region and language settings dialog, you can also choose the server location if you want to masquerade at a different location.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I expected to find it! I've edited the question to show the dialogue with it missing.

Comment: Nice! I never noticed that. I just pulled up a few servers I have on rackspace, and they all show it. I bet it is something unique to that AMI.  I bet you could create an AMI using amazons tools and port it up to ec2 though.